# netty websockets hornetq 2.2.5 fails with latest chrome on Sec-WebSocket-Accept header

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, netty, hornetq

I am trying to run the netty stomp websockets example in the hornetq 2.2.5 distribution but it does not work with Chrome latest version. Chrome shows the following error in the javascript console -

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing
```

Reading on forums seems to suggest that this is related to Netty itself. I understand that chrome is too fast to adapt to the changing websockets protocol so its complaining about a header not being returned from the server.Netty version with the hornetq distro seems to be 3.2.3. If this related to Netty only? Can this be fixed by using a later version of Netty with the same distibution of hornetq?

Comment: I'm no expert of hornetq but you may want to try upgrade to netty-3.3.1.Final and see if it helps

Comment: did try that.. by replacing the jar. No change. It seems hornetq has a websockethandler which is still on the older version of the protocol [link]http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hornetq/hornetq-core/2.2.9.AS7.Final/org/hornetq/core/protocol/stomp/WebSocketServerHandler.java?av=f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think HornetQ is using the older netty `websocket` package.  To support chrome, HornetQ needs to use the new `websocketx` package.

Both the `websocket` and `websocketx` package will be supplied in Netty v3.X for backwards compatibility.  Some people have extended the `websocket` package and have written their own code to support newer versions of the websocket protocol.

In Netty v4, the `websocket` package has been droped.